# fragment anchored to appbarlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-appbarlayout, layout-anchor

I want to achieve a UI in which the fragment should be anchored to appbarlayout.
What I've done so far is, I've set anchor-gravity to my fragment `second_container` as **bottom|center** and transacted one fragment inside it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The output should be like this:

[image: desired output]

what I'm getting is:

[image: current output]

As you can see, the fragment content is getting overlapped on appbarlayout, what is the problem here? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: give marginTop in minus like -20dp

Comment: Abhinav, that doesn't solve the problem. Giving margin would eliminate the use of `layout-anchor` and `anchor-gravity` and causing the fragment content to be rendered below the appbarlayout whilst the output should be such that fragment should float at bottom end of appbarlayout view as shown in desired ouput.

Comment: android:id="@+id/second_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:marginTop="-25dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

Comment: By using marginTop, the contents are gone completely. @AbhinavGupta

Comment: contact me on this mail :- abhinavguptabit@gmail.com